# I want to create a dynamic table that features data entered by a user when the user hits submit/save (novice programmer)

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I am very new to coding in general, and thought the best way to learn would be to make an app of some kind, and went with a simple one. The premise is that if an employee has lost their work pass/badge, and need a temporary one for the day, the receptionist/security can input the employees information along with their assigned badge number into a form. From this form, it is automatically inputted into a table. Within this table, there'll be a checkbox to validate the return of the pass at the end of the day.

I have two problems: the first is I cannot get the data for anything except the employees name and date of birth (so contact numbers/addresses etc. aren't showing), to show when I hit save. The second is I must have hit a wrong key somewhere as now NONE of the data (name and dob included) are showing when I hit save. I have looked over my code several times, however, as I said I am very new to all this (this being my first project), and I'm not sure what I'm supposed to be looking for.

If you guys could offer some guidance, I'd be extremely grateful.

PS. The colours are as they are so I can easily see what I'm changing when playing with the css - the final version will look much better (I hope!). My apologies again for the poor standard of coding: I'm sure it's riddled with obvious signs of an absolute beginner...

**This is my HTML file:**

```
 <html>

  <head>
    <title>
      My Document
    </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />

    <script src="default.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

  </head>

  <body onload="doShowAll()">
    <h1>Pass Manager</h1>
    <div id="form" name="input" title="Input Form">
    <form >
        Name:  <input type="text" name="name" />
      </br>
        Date of Birth: <input type="date" name="dob" />
        House Number: <input type="number" name="house_number" />
        Postcode: <input type="text" name="postcode" />
        Contact Number: <input type="number" name="contact_number" />
        Email: <input type="email" name="email" />
      </br>
        Pass number: <input type="number" name="pass_number" />
    </form>
  </div>

    <form name=Information>
  <div id="PlayArea">
    <table>
      <tr>

        <td><b>Name:</b> <input type="text" name="name"></td>
        <td><b>Date of Birth:</b> <input type="text" name="dob"></td>
        <td><b>House Number:</b> <input type="text" name="houseNumber"></td>
        <td><b>Postcode:</b> <input type="text" name="postcode"></td>
        <td><b>Contact Number:</b> <input type="number" name="contactNumber"></td>
        <td><b>Email:</b> <input type="email" name="email" /></td>
        <td><b>Pass Number:</b> <input type="number" name="passNumber"></td>

      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>
            <input type=button value="Save"   onclick="SaveItem()">
            <input type=button value="Modify" onclick="ModifyItem()">
            <input type=button value="Remove" onclick="RemoveItem()">
          </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>

  <div id="items_table">
    <h2>Loaned Badges</h2>
    <table id=list></table>
    <p>
      <label><input type=button value="Clear" onclick="ClearAll()">
        <i>* Removes all items</i></label>
    </p>
  </div>
</form>

  </body>

</html>
```

**And this is my JavaScript file:**

```
function SaveItem() {
              var name = document.forms.Information.name.value;
              var data = document.forms.Information.data.value;
                localStorage.setItem(name, data);
                doShowAll();
            }

function ModifyItem() {
                var name = document.forms.Information.name.value;
                document.forms.Information.data.value = localStorage.getItem(name);
                doShowAll();
            }
function RemoveItem() {
                var name = document.forms.Information.name.value;
                document.forms.Information.data.value = localStorage.removeItem(name);
                doShowAll();
            }
function ClearAll() {
                localStorage.clear();
                doShowAll();
            }
function CheckBrowser() {
                if ('localStorage' in window && window['localStorage'] !== null) {
                  return true;
                }
                else {
                   return false;
                }
            }
function doShowAll() {
                    if (CheckBrowser()) {
                    var key = "";
                    var list = "<tr><th>Name</th><th>Date of Birth</th><th>House Number</th><th>Postcode</th><th>Contact Number</th><th>Email</th><th>Pass Number</th></tr>\n";
                    var i = 0;
for (i = 0; i <= localStorage.length - 1; i++) {
                            key = localStorage.key(i);
                            list += "<tr><td>" + key + "</td>\n<td>"
                            + localStorage.getItem(key) + "</td></tr>\n";
                              }
if (list == "<tr><th>Name</th><th>Date of Birth</th><th>House Number</th><th>Postcode</th><th>Contact Number</th><th>Email</th><th>Pass Number</th></tr>\n") {
                            list += "<tr><td><i>empty</i></td>\n<td><i>empty</i></td></tr>\n";
                              }
                            document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = list;
                                } else {
                              alert('Cannot store user preferences as your browser do not support local storage');
                                }
                            }
for (i = 0; i <= localStorage.length - 1; i++) {
                      key = localStorage.key(i);
                      list += "<tr><td>" + key + "</td>\n<td>"
                      + localStorage.getItem(key) + "</td></tr>\n";
              }
function CheckBrowser() {
                if ('localStorage' in window && window['localStorage'] !== null) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                        return false;
                }
              }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two forms on your page. The two forms look to be similar (not sure why). The first one doesn't have a name, so your code won't be able to access it.

I would recommend that you look at some kind of templating system (like Angular).

What you are doing uses plain old javascript, which isn't wrong, but the way you are dynamically creating javascript is very much a deprecated technique because there are many better ways to do it now. You might as well learn good techniques in a modern framework, because you will need them sooner or later.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're having is in SaveItem(). **Data** isn't a field in Information. I've changed it to **dob** and is appears to work

```
function SaveItem() {
          var name = document.forms.Information.name.value;
          // data isn't a member of the Information form.
          // var data = document.forms.Information.data.value;
          var data = document.forms.Information.dob.value;
            localStorage.setItem(name, data);
            doShowAll();
        }
```

It's useful if you can show a working example of your code. I've thrown your code into codepen here if you want to see. [Codepen example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vyEKgB?editors=1111)